# Chrome extension can not inject my script to iframe that created by tinyMCE

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tinymce

I'm developing a chrome extension.
I want to inject my script to every page/iframe to get selected words.

Normally Chrome does everything thing to inject my script to all frames. I just declare in file manifest

It's looks like below:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file://*/*"],
    "css": ["wdict_style.css", "jquery-ui-1.10.3.ui-classic.css", "jquery-ui-1.10.3.ui-compact.css"],
    "js": ["jquery-2.0.3.min.js", "jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js", "common.js", "dClient.min.js", "content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "all_frames": true
}],
"permissions": ["storage", "contextMenus", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "*://*/*"],
```

It's working fine with other pages/iframes.

However it seems to not work with iframe that created by tinyMCE.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Show us _teh codez_! We have no idea how you inject your script. Also, please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This might have something to do with `about:blank` origin. Try to switch permissions to `<all_urls>` add `"match_about_blank" : true` to the content script declaration in the manifest as described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/content_scripts). I believe it [might not yet be](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55084) in the Chrome code though.

Comment: Thank you to reply. I've tried as you recommended. It still not solve my problem. :(

Comment: It seems the content script is not injected to blank iframes.
The option "match_about_blank" is mentioned to solve this problem, however it's just available on Chrome Dev version. I see it works well on chrome 37. :)